# CentOS i686 virtualization

Tags: centos, virtualbox, x86

I am 100% newbie to unix, so my question is quite simple, although very important to me :-)

I need to install a software that runs on CentOS with i386 architecture.
Since I do not have CentOS on my machine, I am planning to use VirtualBox (on a windows x64 host) to install the operating system.

My questions are:

- Can I run a CentOs i386 on a Windows x64 system (with virtual box)?
- Is 32bit synonym of i386? Can I use the 32bit image from [osboxes](http://www.osboxes.org/centos/) ??

ps: I have seen this [link](https://hereirestinremorse.wordpress.com/virtualbox/this-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detected-an-i686-cpu-unable-to-boot-please-use-a-kernel-appropriate-for-your-cpu/), but it is the opposite problem: running a x64 guest OS on a x32 host os.

Comment: Have you tried?  Trying is a good way to learn.

Comment: Yes, You can run 32 bit CentOs on a 64 bit Windows host system. But I am down voting this since you haven't tried anything related to that.

Comment: @Thushi Sorry, should _not_ be a any problem. :-)

Comment: ok. thanks...   Just to be sure: Can I use the 32bit image from osboxes ??

Comment: @guilhermecgs Get the official ISO instead, from https://wiki.centos.org/Download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no issues running a 32 bit CentOS installation on Windows in VirtualBox. Just create a virtual machine of type "Linux" and version "Red Hat (32-bit)".

`i386` is usually used to refer to the Intel-compatible 32 bit architecture.

The official CentOS ISOs are available from https://wiki.centos.org/Download